# Can't figure out why a cron job isn't working

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have an odd situation where I have a cron job set up to execute a shell file once a day, and based on the syslog the cron job IS being called as intended, and by the proper user that should be executing it. But, the script is supposed to update a value in a database, and when I check the database the value has not been updated. Yet, if I *manually* run the shell file as that same user it executes as intended and updates the database value as I expect. So it doesn't seem to be a problem with the shell script having an error or the cron user not having permission for the file, since it's the same user as the file owner. So somehow it is calling the cron job to execute this script, and I know the script works when run by that user, but for some reason the script does not actually seem to be running successfully when called by cron. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: There is insufficient information to definitively help without seeing the script.  My guess is that the path  (ie path variable = where the IS looks for executables)  is different for you and the cron job.  Try adding full paths to all commands in the script.   Also, look at the database log to see what, if anything is being sent as a db query.

Comment: Please add the cron line you’re using to the question so we don’t have to guess what might be wrong. Also, add some debugging output to the script and log it to a file for later examination.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to remember that cron scripts don't run in the same environment as a regular user. (Cron's don't run on top of bash, they just run).  So you can't assume the PATH environment variable is going to be good to go.  Usually if you just make sure you aren't using any relative paths, it will work.

Comment: I was hoping this would fix it, but I added the output of the user's 'echo $PATH' to the cron file and it still didn't run as expected today.